# assert returning a value in c++

Tags: c++, assert, return-type

It be very useful to have assert returning a value in c++ like this:

```
SomeType someValue = assert(getSomeValue());
```

instead of

```
SomeType someValue = getSomeValue();
assert(someValue);
```

Is there any standard way to do this?

Comment: What possible use case is there where this would be "Very useful"

Comment: It's useful, because it's laconic.

Comment: Be wary of [the `assert` macro](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert). First of all it will not do anything at all if the macro `NDEBUG` is defined (which it should be for release builds), and otherwise if the assertion fails it will crash the program which isn't very user-friendly.

Comment: @infinitezero I suppose it's when `getSomeValue` returns a pointer or a stream or anything ele contextually convertible to `bool` and you want to assert that it's "good" (not null, not failed etc).

Comment: Also, the expression in the macro is treated as a boolean result, not as a value.

Comment: There isn't (no standard library facility ever calls `assert`) but you can write your own function if you want.

Comment: If `NDEBUG` is not defined (i.e. in production/release code) `assert()` can and often is a macro that eats its arguments, and produces no result or value.  So this is not possible, unless you make specific (and non-guaranteed) assumptions about how `assert()` is defined.    Also, conciseness of code is not a good reason to claim "it will be very useful" - in my experience, most developers who sweat over conciseness of C++ code write pretty poor code (e.g. high incidence of undefined behaviours).

Comment: The code as posted `SomeType someValue = assert(getSomeValue());` is meaningless. You need to elaborate the idea. Is it kind of unwrap-or-abort for likes of optional, pointer, smart pointer? Yes it would be better than for example prefix `operator*` of `std::optional` (unwrap-or-ub) as calling `abort()` is defined behavior. But then perhaps name it `unwrap`, not assert.

Answer (score 4):

1. No, there is no standard way of doing this.
2. You can easily write your own macro (`assertTrue()`, `assertNotNull()`, etc.)
3. I would advise against this, because assertions should stand out, and the way to make something stand out is to have it occupy a line of its own.

Comment: asserts are also not meant to be for production code. Only for the programmer.
They should not change or decide business logic

Comment: @Raildex I do not know what you mean by "asserts are also not meant to be for production code. Only for the programmer." As for the remainder of your comment, yes, of course. I am doing the OP the favor of assuming that if they choose to create such macros, they know how to define them so that they have no effect on non-debug builds.  But so that we are clear, I maintain that it is indeed possible to write those macros so that they have no effect on non-debug builds.